# textarea.ms-long for single line text

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have been using the following to increase the width of my text box on a custom form using SPD 2013.

```
 <style>
       textarea.ms-long{width: 400px;}
 </style>
```

What is the class / definition for a single line text box for a custom list form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single line text fields have "input" tags and not "textarea". So the style should be applied like this:

```
<style>
   input.ms-long{width: 400px;}
</style>

<!--apply the class "ms-long" to the input field-->
<input class="ms-long" id="yourID">
```

Comment: EXCELLENT!  What is the tag for a drop down box?

Comment: Tag for dropdown is <select>.
But you need to put your options in the dropdown inside <option> tag . so the whole element becomes like this:

<select id="ddr">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<style>

input.ms-long {
    width: 50px ! important;
}
</style>
```

**Output**

[image]